# Bootstrap - fixed to top navbar with 3 text elements

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

What's the most reliable and efficient way to make bootstrap fixed to top header with 3 text elements: 2 on the sides and 1 in the center.
It's important that the header must not fold or collapse on mobile or tablet.

Issues:

- the center text element isn't centered (classes navbar-right/left/center don't work)
- the header keeps on
  collapsing when resizing.

This is my current code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;">
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class='navbar-left'>
        <p class="navbar-text" id="left">Text text text
            <br>text text</p>
    </div>
    <div class='navbar-center'>
        <p class="navbar-text" id="center">Text text text
            <br>text text</p>
    </div>
    <div class='navbar-right' id="right">
        <p class="navbar-text">Text text text
            <br>text text</p>
    </div>
</nav>
<!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="buffer">
        <div class="container">
             <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

            <p>This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called a jumbotron and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more &raquo;</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e3ppnbxv/)

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap docs say:
"The navbar collapses into its vertical mobile view when the viewport is narrower than @grid-float-breakpoint, and expands into its horizontal non-mobile view when the viewport is at least @grid-float-breakpoint in width. Adjust this variable in the Less source to control when the navbar collapses/expands. The default value is 768px (the smallest "small" or "tablet" screen)."

Override the less variable `@grid-float-breakpoint` to 0px for eliminating collapsability.

For centering, You may wish to consider just using custom code in the header since you're not using the bootstrap responsive features.

Comment: Thanks! And what about correctly positioning text elements?

Comment: I don't believe `navbar-center` is a Bootstrap class.  You can try using `navbar-left` and `navbar-right`, and then customize something to put one box in the center.  What I was getting at with my comment about just using custom code, is that there are a lot of inherited styles on all the navbar elements, and understanding them may take longer than just writing your own navbar code since you're not really using Bootstrap's navbar features accept for fixed-top.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `navbar-center` class in Bootstrap 3, and there is no longer a `row-fluid` class (the DIV tag is not closed in your HTML).

You can create a custom class to center the text and use pull-right and pull-left classes since they're not impacted by the collapsing navbar:

http://codeply.com/go/R2JwHRpzXN

```
.navbar-center
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```